# A posteriori probability distribution of random vector given noisy estimate

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors, normal-distribution, bayesian

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a $N$-dimensional random vector distributed as $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$. Let

$$\hat{\mathbf{x}} = \sqrt{1-\eta^{2}} \mathbf{x} + \eta \mathbf{z}$$

be a noisy estimate of $\mathbf{x}$, with $\eta \in [0,1]$ and where the noise vector $\mathbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$ is independent on $\mathbf{x}$.

From the above equation, the distribution of $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ given $\mathbf{x}$ reads as $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{1-\eta^{2}} \mathbf{x}, \eta^{2} \mathbf{I})$.

But how can I write the a posteriori probability distribution of the real $\mathbf{x}$ given its noisy estimate $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$?

- Tentative solution: When $\eta^{2}=0$, we should have $\mathbf{x} | \hat{\mathbf{x}} \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{\mathbf{x}}, \mathbf{0})$, whereas when $\eta^{2}=1$, we should have $\mathbf{x} | \hat{\mathbf{x}} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy to write out the joint distribution, and convince yourself it is indeed a multivariate normal, as
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{N} \left(\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{z} \\ \mathbf{x} \\ \hat{\mathbf{x}}
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}\eta \\
\mathbf{0} &\mathbf{\Sigma} & \mathbf{\Sigma}\sqrt{1 -\eta^2} \\
\eta\mathbf{I} & \sqrt{1-\eta^2} \mathbf{\Sigma} & \sqrt{1-\eta^2}\mathbf{\Sigma}\sqrt{1-\eta^2} + \eta^2\mathbf{I}\end{bmatrix} \right).
\end{align*}
$$
From this it is easy to read off the joint distribution of $\mathbf{x},\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ after marginalising out $\mathbf{z}$, and then using known results for the [conditional distribution of multivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) we have
$$
\mathbf{x} \, | \, \hat{\mathbf{x}} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x}\,|\,\mathbf{\mu}_{x|\hat{x}}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{x|\hat{x}}\right),
$$
where
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{\mu}_{x|\hat{x}}&=\sqrt{1 - \eta^2}\mathbf{\Sigma}\left[\sqrt{1-\eta^2}\mathbf{\Sigma}\sqrt{1-\eta^2} + \eta^2\mathbf{I}\right]^{-1}\hat{\mathbf{x}},  \\
&=\left(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} + \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\eta^2}}{\eta}\right)^2\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{1-\eta^2}}{\eta^2}\hat{\mathbf{x}}, \qquad \eta \neq 0 ,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{x|\hat{x}} &= \mathbf{\Sigma} - \sqrt{1-\eta^2}\mathbf{\Sigma}\left[ \sqrt{1-\eta^2}\mathbf{\Sigma}\sqrt{1-\eta^2} + \eta^2\mathbf{I} \right]^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma}\sqrt{1-\eta^2} \\
&= \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} + \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\eta^2}}{\eta}\right)^2\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \qquad \eta \neq 0.
\end{align*}
So that in particular when $\eta = 0$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\mu_{x|\hat{x}} &= \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\hat{\mathbf{x}} = \hat{\mathbf{x}} \\
\Sigma_{x | \hat{x}} &= \mathbf{\Sigma} - \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{0}
\end{align*}
$$
as you would hope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, there was a typo (now corrected) in the variance of the conditional distribution of $\hat{\mathbf{x}} | \mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Also, from the joint distribution that you wrote, it seems that $\mathbf{z}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ are independent, which is not correct.

Comment: Updated to correct the covariance and hopefully made it explicit when the matrix inverse term can be tidied up, but let me know if you spot any other issues

Comment: Thanks, now it's much clearer. The only thing is that I'm not able to obtain your value for the covariance: instead, I obtain $\mathbf{\Sigma} - \frac{1-\eta^{2}}{\eta^{2}} \big( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} + \frac{1-\eta^{2}}{\eta^{2}} \mathbf{I} \big)^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}$.

Comment: $\left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} + \frac{1-\eta^2}{\eta^2}\mathbf{I} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{\Sigma}\left( \mathbf{I} + \frac{1-\eta^2}{\eta^2}\mathbf{\Sigma} \right)^{-1}$ - the expressions should be the same, although note that you do need to keep track of the sign of $1-\eta^2$